# How to stop all threads in MicroPython?

Tags: python, multithreading, micropython

I am building a system using MicroPython on a ESP32 using multi-threading, and MicroPython uses the _thread module, not the threading module. I want to be able to stop the execution of the whole program by raising a KeyboardInterrupt, but when I do this only the main thread exits and the remaing threads remain active. As far as I know the _thread module has no daemon functionality when starting a thread. How can I achieve to exit the whole program?

*Edit: Here is the _thread module docs: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/_thread.html#module-_thread

```
import _thread

def check_max_capacity():
    api_call()
    ...

# Check Max Capacity Thread
_thread.start_new_thread(check_max_capacity, ())

try:
    ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exits")
```

Comment: Are the other threads waiting on something? If so, you need to close that something to get them to wake and exit.

Comment: No, they are running on While True's because I need them to be constantly performing api calls

Comment: have you try `python-worker` library? https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/

Comment: @danangjoyoo it is unlikely that code will run on micropython.

Comment: Running a test with _thread on regular python, the process exited with the main thread. I could not reproduce.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the [MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/)? Also have you considered using [uasyncio](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/uasyncio.html) rather than `_thread`? I'm not experienced with either but I know that those who are tend to recommend uasyncio over _thread.